# Codename One: show a (secret) Image from an URL without storing and without caching

Tags: codenameone

I have the following code:

```
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(FontImage.createImage(size, size, ColorUtil.GRAY), true);
String url = "...";
Date date = new Date();
URLImage qrCode = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, date.getTime() + ".png", url, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
qrCode.fetch();
qrCodeLabel.setIcon(qrCode);
```

The `qrCode` image contains a secret that should not be saved on the Storage / FileSystem and that should not be cached in any way. It should be shown to the user only one time.

Because these requirements, of course my code doesn't work as I need, because the image is saved and cached. I prefer that the execution of the code stops until the image is downloaded, instead this code firstly shows the placeholder, then shows the image.

So, my question is which code can I use to show an image in a Label, downloading it from an url with these requirements:

- no cache;
- no storing;
- block of the execution until the image is ready (I have a loading Dialog that I want to dispose when the image is ready).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLImage` was designed for caching. You can obviously delete the storage file but it goes a bit against the core purpose of the class.

Just use something like:

```
ConnectionRequest q = new ConnectionRequest(imageUrl, false) {
     public void postResponse() {
         EncodedImage qr = EncodedImage.create(getResponseData());
         labelForQr.setIcon(qr);
         parentForm.revalidate();
     }
};
addToQueue(q);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! To get a complete synchronous operation, I used `CN.addToQueueAndWait(q);`